# Merge Rows in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report, which I already developed in below format.[image]

My new requirement is to add two new columns to the report to show “Total Men”
Total Men column should merge into one, if the Date, Department and Vendor is same. 
And it should show the Total Men which is = No of men Day shift + No of Men Night shift

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a `Formula Field` e.g. `ShiftTotal` and edit it to insert following code:

   ```
   WhilePrintingRecords;
   numberVar ShiftSum;
   if {table_name.Date_Field} = Next({table_name.Date_Field}) 
     and {table_name.Department_Field} = Next({table_name.Department_Field})
     and {table_name.Vendor_Field} = Next({table_name.Vendor_Field}) then
       ShiftSum := ShiftSum + {table_name.Men_Field} + Next({table_name.Men_Field})
   else
       ShiftSum := 0;
   ```
2. Place `ShiftTotal` in the *Details* section next to `Men_Field`
3. Format `ShiftTotal` to enable `Suppress if Zero` in Custom Style of Number tab
4. **Sort** your report by Date, Department and Vendor fields.

Above solution will work if there are maximum two records for same Date, Department and Vendor. Otherwise, it would be better to use Cross-Tab format, which (IMO) is better for such summaries.